Added wakelock_plus plugin into my exiting flutter project but not able to use it
Here is my pubspec.yaml file
name: cali_clinic
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
  connectivity_plus: ^5.0.2
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.6
  flutter_custom_selector: ^0.0.3
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
  intl: ^0.19.0
  go_router: ^12.1.1
  flutter_mobx: ^2.2.0
  mobx: ^2.2.1
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  dio: ^5.4.0
  logger: ^2.0.2+1
  firebase_core: ^2.24.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.6
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.6
  flutter_local_notifications: ^16.2.0
  flutter_svg_provider: ^1.0.6
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.4
  get_it: ^7.6.4
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  wakelock_plus: ^1.2.4
  country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
  agora_rtc_engine: ^6.3.0
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.6
  build_runner: ^2.4.7
  mobx_codegen: ^2.4.0
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
  
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/svg/


  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400


    - family: Roboto Regular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400

and after running flutter pub get command, it shows this...

pubspec.lock
 wakelock_plus:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: wakelock_plus
      sha256: c8b7cc80f045533b40a0e6c9109905494e3cf32c0fbd5c62616998e0de44003f
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.4"

But now when I import the package into my dart class it gives an error


Following is the output of Flutter doctor as well...


Have you tried restarting your IDE? or restarting your PC?

It worked, restarting IDE. Feeling like stupid not thinking of this as a solution. Thanks mate.
